# PDO :: bind variable with LIKE

Tags: php, pdo, bindparam

Can anyone help me

This works fine ::

```
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SHOW TABLES FROM db LIKE 'xyz'"); //tablename hardcoded
            $stmt->execute();
            $rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  //fetchAll
```

However if I try to bind my table name, as it will be dynamic in my script ::

```
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SHOW TABLES FROM db LIKE :tbl"); //tablename hardcoded
            $tbl = "xyz";
            $stmt->bindParam(":tbl", $tbl, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

This gives error,

```
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SHOW TABLES FROM cens LIKE ?");
            $tbl = "xyz";
            $stmt->bindParam(1, $tbl, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

This also gives error,

Error is

Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/PDO/test.php:132
Stack trace:

## 0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/PDO/test.php(132): PDO->prepare('SHOW TABLES FRO...')

I tried with quotes, both in query and in bind variable, but it didn't work

I want to bind the table name,

Comment: Whats wrong with you guys, why am I given negative point always, I always research first and then ask. my last questing was also given negative point. I havent found any solution for both of the questions. just given the negative points.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$string = 'xyz';
$somethingelse ="%".$string."%";
$sth =$dbh->prepare("select * from tablename WHERE something LIKE :somethingelse")
$sth->bindParam(":somethingelse",$somethingelse)
```

Another alternative would be to do:

```
$string = 'xyz';
$somethingelse ="%".$string."%";
$sth =$dbh->prepare("select * from tablename WHERE something LIKE CONCAT(:string, '%')")
$sth->bindParam(":string",$string)
```

Either of these methods should work for you.

Comment: That didnt work either. I just want to know that the table exists in other database or not. dont want to use the SELECT clause.

Comment: These don't make much sense and there are unused variables.... and it doesn't answer the OP's question.